# jQuery slider and background image works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I just uploaded a wordpress site to a live server, and I'm seeing that the background image and slider are not working in Chrome.  I have no idea what could be wrong as the jquery is loading correctly.  Anyone able to see something obvious I may have missed?

Here is the site:
https://learnmarimba.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website uses the https (secure) protocol and you are using resources that are called using http. Chrome does not like the mix of https and http. You can see the warnings in the Crome console.

Omit the protocol. So instead of

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

use

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

Also have a look at this post on [protocol relative urls](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

As a side note, the Google Analytics inclusion snippet checks the protocol the current webpage was called with and uses that in the url to include a javascript file.

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

[Source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en)

Comment: ok.  So I should just be linking to a jquery file  on my own host?

Comment: No, just remove http: or https: from the url

Comment: Ah-saw your reply after just linking to my own copy of jquery.  It works now.  Thank you!